# Acuamtica Cases additional grid not displaying all PXSelect related data rows from Relations grid

Tags: c#, acumatica

Using the Acumatica code below, I was able to conditionally create a new grid in the Cases screen; however, the PXSelect command is not displaying all of the rows in grid.
What I am trying to do is based on the "Relations" take the value of CRRelation.targetNoteID and pull all of the ARRegister data into a new grid called "CAM Info".  But the "CAM Info" graph view is only displaying the very first row from "Relations" and not all the other ones.  (See the screen shot images for reference)
How do I need to write the Acumatica code to find, select and display ALL of the rows in the "CAM Info" grid?

````
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Data.EP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.CR.Workflows;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.SM;
using PX.TM;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{

  public class CRCaseMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
  {     
      
     
    #region Event Handlers
        protected virtual void CRCase_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
          {
            InvokeBaseHandler?.Invoke(cache, e);
            var row = (CRCase)e.Row;
            if (row != null)
              {
                if (row.CaseClassID == "CAM")
                  {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<Objects.CR.CRCaseExt.usrRMAReason>(cache, row, false);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<Objects.CR.CRCaseExt.usrSupportCategory >(cache, row, false);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<Objects.CR.CRCaseExt.usrContractDesc>(cache, row, false);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<Objects.CR.CRCaseExt.usrCaseStage>(cache, row, false);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<Objects.CR.CRCaseExt.usrIGAHEquipmentID>(cache, row, false);                 
                  }
                

              } 
            
          } 
  
    #endregion
               
        
    // Following view delaration populates the ARRegister info; but only one line            
    #region Selects  
       public PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegister.noteID, Equal<CurrentValue<CRRelation.targetNoteID>>>> CAMRelationsView;
    #endregion
             
 
      
  }
}```
[![Cases Relations Tab grid][1]][1]
[![Cases CAM Info Tab grid][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4KA0.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBYNQ.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare view is incorrect. You need to declare it like this

```
public PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegister.noteID, Equal<Current<CRRelation.targetNoteID>>>> CAMRelationsView;
```

Also, you need to set 2 more settings

1. `SyncPosition` for the Relation grid should be set to `true`
2. on the `AutoCallBack` events you need to write a dynamic update for your own grid view with grid `ID`.

`Current<Field>` - Inserts the field value from the `Current` property of the cache. If the `Current` property is null or the field value is null, the parameter will be replaced by the default value.
`CurrentValue<Field>` - Equivalent to the `Current` parameter, but is used in the `PXProjection` attribute.
Display all `ARRegister`. It depends on what record you will enter on the Relation tab.

1. If it will be a `Customer` record you can select all `ARRegister` for that customer
2. if it will be an `ARRegister` record you can select all related transactions
   In case `ARRegister` is a payment you can select all applied invoices
   if `ARRegister` is an invoice you can select all applied payments

Comment: Vardan, thank you.  The one setting I do not know how to set is the AutoCallBack.  On the Screens under the Layout Properties which of the options there do I set?  I am guessing I have to set "Enabled = true", but do I also then set the name of grid (which is grdCAMInfo" in "Argument", "Command", and/or "Target" options?

Also, can this be set using ASPX and if so, what does that code look like?  My apologies, I am new to Acumatica.

Comment: I think I made the changes you proposed correctly; however the "grdCAMInfo" (grid id) is still only pulling the first row of the associated ARRegister data.  I will try 

```#region Selects  
       public PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegister.noteID, Equal<Current<CRRelation.targetNoteID>>>> CAMRelationsView;
 #endregion
    <px:PXGrid ID="grdRelations" 
    
      <AutoCallBack Enabled="True" />
      <AutoCallBack Command="Refresh" />
      <AutoCallBack Target="grdCAMInfo" /></px:PXGrid>

      <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="grdCAMInfo"
```

Comment: I did not notice initially, but now, even though it is showing only one row still in the grdCAMInfo grid, it is displaying the 'last' entry from the Relations grid, rather than the first row.  However, again, not all are displayed still

Comment: You see one line of `ARRegister` because `NoteID` is unique for each record

Comment: ah, ok. Not really what I wanted to do, however I can make that work for the user.  Question : Is there any way to display all of the associated rows from Relations grid in the associated CAM Info grid?  (I suppose I am asking if there is a way to perform a "foreach CRRelation.targetNoteID then display that ARRegister row".
If that cannot be done, I am ok with it, simply wanted to ask if such a thing was possible, and if so, how could that be done.

Comment: the answer is updated